# python django models problems

Tags: django, python-3.x

I made standard class of django.model

```
    class Standard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='default name')
    description = models.TextField()
    link = models.TextField()
    createat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    random = models.TextField(max_length=300, default="random")
    category = models.ForeignKey(StandardCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requirement = models.ForeignKey(StandardRequirement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

but  have the problem when I compile it

```
web_1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: app_standardrequirement.createat
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Show `StandardRequirement` model definition. Have you applied all migrations?

Comment: It's collumn was work   createat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Comment: But it's don't work correct, i don't see it in my admin pannel.

Comment: Add `StandardRequirement` model definition to your question, run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py showmigrations`, add output of showmigrations to your question.